# How to keep Zotero collections in sync with collaborators via git?

Tags: git, zotero, bibtex

I am using Zotero/Latex for academic writing and citations, yet I am wondering about the cleanest way to collaborate on a scientific manuscript via Zotero and git/github.

I am happily using the BetterBibtex plugin for Zotero. I activated the "Keep updated" option via BetterBibtex, so that changes in my Zotero collection are automatically written to the .bib file. This is good, since now I can track the .bib (basically text) via git.

But what about the other way - how do I get any changes from the .bib (e.g. my remote collaborator added something to the collection) to the Zotero collection?

Of course it is possible to do it manually after git pull:

- delete the Zotero collection;
- then import new Zotero collection via .bib file

But this seems cumbersome and prone to errors. Does someone know of an automatic way to get this functionality?

Comment: Synchronization is a very finicky thing.  Even for me just synchronizing things against Dropbox (using 3rd party tools, arguably) can be a real problem.  I wish you luck.  Good question.  I just don't have the foundation to have an answer.